# Kubernetes POD automation - schedule a new deployment based on the successful completion of the old deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I'm looking for some help in scheduling deployments in Kubernetes.

I need to schedule a new deployment based on the successful completion of an old deployment. How can I achieve that in Kubernetes?

My first deployment will be running for 3-4 hours doing fetching some data. Once it gets completed I need to delete that deployment and deploy a new one.

Comment: Do you need to fetch new code for deployment  or what? I mean I can not understand the reason, you could deploy your app and then update it by rolling update strategy, or You can use cron jobs it will be start on schedule. Also take a look to PreStop Hook https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/

Comment: Hi Nick, I will be running a deployment with some image . Once its gets completed successfully, i need to delete the existing deployment and do a new deployment with a new image based on the successful completion.

Comment: It looks like making Docker image, If it is you may just use docker instead of kubernetes to achieve this.